# I want to print an output from live run of pycharm to a simple plain text of qtdesinh

Tags: windows, terminal, printing, output, qplaintextedit

I don't have any code snippet for this question. I want to print whatever output is showing to run windows to a plain text editor

I don't have any code snippet for this question. I want to print whatever output is showing to run windows to a plain text editor. I need it for a project purpose.